# I can't make ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard() work in Espresso 2.2.2

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, android-espresso

I'm trying to test an app and I require to hide the keyboard, because I cannot click button because of it. So, I added Espresso in build.gradle:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
```

and tried to use this from `android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions` library:

```
ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard();
```

Test runs successfully, but fails after typing some text in EditText in my layout. And keyboard is still there, showing.

P.S. I realized it was keyboard's fault after [reading this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29792724/4279735)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`ViewAction` on its own does not do anything unless it is used in the `ViewInteraction`. That means that you need to either chain it with your previous action in `perform()` like this: `onView()..perform(typeText(..), closeSoftKeyboard())` or use a built-in helper which is in `Espresso` class like this: `Espresso.closeSoftKeyboard()`

Comment: Yes it solved keyboard problem, but the error stil exists.. Thanks anyway.

Comment: They really should give these a different name. Once there's an import, it's not really obvious that a method called "closeSoftKeyboard()" only works when chained to ViewActions. I got stung by this one but your answer helped me. From now on I'll be explicit with Espresso.closeSoftKeyboard(). That's what they do in the examples, I just didn't see why until now :)

Answer (score 9):

You can implement this:

```
fun hideKeyboard() {
    onView(ViewMatchers.isRoot()).perform(ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard())
  }
```

After that only  use this: `paymentMethodPage.hideKeyboard()`